# Mongodb subquery for the given sql (Select * from table where id in (select distincnt(id) from table );)

Tags: mongodb, subquery

Mongodb subquery

Hi, Can someone help me in getting the equivalent mongo sub-query for the given sql?

Query :

```sql
Select * from table where id in (select distincnt(id) from table );
```

Comment: hey - Gibbs trying it out . will get back to you .

Comment: I had to delete my answer as it didn't serve your purpose exactly. Why don't you go for denormalised version?

Comment: actually i am trying to figure out how we can acheive subquery in mongo.